# Apply CSS "stripe" effect to dynamically-inserted table rows in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have made a table. In that, when I click on button, a row is added. I want to assign alternate color to the row inserted.

```js
$("#new-row").click(function() {
  $('#first').clone(true).insertAfter('#demo tbody>tr:last');

  if ($('#demo tr:last').hasClass("lgrey")) {
    $('#demo tr:last').removeClass("lgrey");
    $('#demo tr:last').addClass("dgrey");
  } else if ($('#demo tr:last').hasClass("dgrey")) {
    $('#demo tr:last').removeClass("dgrey");
    $('#demo tr:last').addClass("lgrey");
  };

});
```

```css
.lgrey {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.dgrey {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="demo">
  <tr>
    <th>H1</th>
    <th>H2</th>
    <th>H3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="lgrey" id="first">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button id="new-row">ADD ROW</button>
```

But running this code does not give desired result.

Please help in assigning an alternate color to inserted rows.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/5292/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need JavaScript for this . . . use the [`:nth-child(an+b)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) selector instead. This approach is much clearer than messing around with unnecessary classes and jQuery code.

Replace the `.lgrey` and `.dgrey` selectors with  `#demo tr:nth-child(2n+2)`,  and `#demo tr:nth-child(2n+3)`, respectively.

(Note that using `even` and `odd`, as some others have suggested, will not allow you to leave the header row unstyled.)

```js
$('#new-row').click(function () {
  $('#first').clone(true).insertAfter('#demo tr:last')
})
```

```css
#demo tr:nth-child(2n+2) {
  background-color: #eee;
}

#demo tr:nth-child(2n+3) {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="demo">
  <tr>
    <th>H1</th>
    <th>H2</th>
    <th>H3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="first">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button id="new-row">ADD ROW</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `tr:nth-child` css property like:

```
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #004400;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

It will handle the alternate color for each `tr` either generated static or dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

You should really use CSS's `nth-child(even)` and `nth-child(even)`for this.

```js
$("#new-row").click(function() {
  $('#first').clone(true).insertAfter('#demo tbody>tr:last');
});
```

```css
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #eee;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #ccc;;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="demo">
  <tr>
    <th>H1</th>
    <th>H2</th>
    <th>H3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="lgrey" id="first">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button id="new-row">ADD ROW</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use css to handle alternate row colors

```
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #eee;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/s1jqboor/1/)

Answer (score 1):

I select row color before add new row as following:

```js
$("#new-row").click(function() {
  if ($('#demo tr:last').hasClass("lgrey")) {
    var add = "dgrey";
    var remove = "lgrey";
  } else if ($('#demo tr:last').hasClass("dgrey")) {
    var add = "lgrey";
    var remove = "dgrey";
  };

  $('#first').clone(true).insertAfter('#demo tbody>tr:last');

  $('#demo tr:last').removeClass(remove);
  $('#demo tr:last').addClass(add);

});
```

```css
.lgrey {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.dgrey {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="demo">
  <tr>
    <th>H1</th>
    <th>H2</th>
    <th>H3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="lgrey" id="first">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button id="new-row">ADD ROW</button>
```